# How to refresh src tag for same URL with different images?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi am using an Angular UI screen and having an Img tag and applying same URL for Src, but each time the image will be different but Url will be the same, now my issue is the Img tag can't refersh the Image. it only get refreshed on page load. how can i refresh img tag with same Url but different Image.

Comment: this is my angular code   <img id="alredyimg" src="{{campaignModel.image}}" ng-show="aimg" style="width: 100%;" />

Comment: Edit you'r question with above code.

Answer (score 2):

i got the solution, i have used `MyImage.src = "http://localhost/image.jpg?" + new Date().getTime();` to refresh Src for same URL.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ng-src directive. 
An example could be:

```
<div ng-init="myVar = 'pic_angular.jpg'">
    <h1>Angular</h1>
    <img ng-src="{{myVar}}">
</div>
```